# Checkbox selected items deletion instead of 1 by 1 deletion (PHP)

Tags: php, html, forms

delete.php

```
session_start();
if (!session_is_registered(validated)) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
elseif (isset($_GET['user']) && isset($_GET['pass'])) {
    $con = mysql_connect('xxx', 'xxx_xxx', 'xxx') or die ("<font color=\"red\">Server is unavailable. Try again later.</font>");
    mysql_select_db("xxx", $con);
    $user=$_GET['user'];
    $pass=$_GET['pass'];
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `accounts` WHERE `username`='$user' AND `password`='$pass'");
    mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

It works with my main thing but the thing I was wondering about is mass deleting.  Using a checkbox selection instead of `<a href="delete.php?user=$row[0]&pass=$row[0]">[x]</a>`

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You need to do your login with a POST.  Passwords in GET requests can be read from server logs or browse history.  You will have to add a form element.

Comment: You might want to cleanup / filter your input before you pass it to mysql. I would also recommend using `post` instead of `get` where database operations and passwords are concerned.

Comment: Additionally, anything that changes the state of the system should be behind a POST anyway.  Some browsers prefetch GET urls, which would be bad if your database empties itself.

Comment: @amccausl thanks

@jeroen I will should include my sanitize class thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have the select boxes share the same name

```
<?php foreach($rows as $row):?>
     <input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="<?php echo $row;?>">
<?php endforeach;?>
```

(in this case $rows is a array of numerical ids use whatever ur row uses as primary key)

this would (when submited to a php script) would give you and array in $_POST called ids;

```
$IDArray = $_POST['ids'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a form with a [checkbox](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TYPE_CHECKBOX.html).  PHP can process all the results with a form submission.